# Excel VBA is using HEAD instead of GET to retrieve image

Tags: excel, vba, rest

Excel 365, VBA talking with Rest API in ASP.NET Core 3.1.

```
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filename).Select
```

Where filename is

```
https://localhost:7257/api/Documents/Master/QRcode/ertdf
```

and 'ertdf' is a randomized key.

From the browser and from Swagger, this works perfectly fine and returns the QR code.
From VBA, it fails with a 405.

Fiddler says that the first is sending a GET request while VBA is sending a HEAD request. Since the image is returned in the body, I can't see why it is using HEAD.
But, given the HEAD request, the 405 makes sense.

To make it more interesting, this was working last week. I reverted the .net code and it still fails.
I don't have an easy way to revert the Excel code, but no known changes have been made to this function.

```
-- Controller code --
namespace API.Controllers {
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DocumentsController: ControllerBase {

    //     [HttpGet, HttpHead]
        [Route("Master/QRcode/{key}")]
        public IActionResult GetQRcode(string key) {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect it makes a `HEAD` request first and then sends the `GET` request if the `HEAD` request succeeds. You shouldn't return HTTP 405 in response to `HEAD`: you should support `HEAD` on every action/handler that supports `GET` anyway - you can get that _for free_ in ASP.NET Core by using `[Route( "/etc/123" )]` instead of only using `[HttpGet( "/etc/123 )]`.

Comment: In the end, I needed [HttpGet, HttpHead] *and* [Route(someroute)].
Can you convert your comment to a response so I can accept it?

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser. It works now, but Fiddler still only shows it as sending a single HEAD request. The response header is 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK | 
Content-Length: 2430028 | 
Content-Type: image/bmp | 
Date: Thu, 17 Nov 2022 19:44:28 GMT | 
Server: Kestrel |  and not surprisingly, the body is empty. But I am getting an image back in the client app. I don't know how it is working without a GET or a body with content.

Comment: Please share the code of your Controller Action. I'm surprised you seem to require `[HttpGet]`, `[HttpHead]`, and `[Route]`....  do you have any attributes on your controller class itself, perhaps? (Hmm, [this article from 2017](https://www.tpeczek.com/2017/10/exploring-head-method-behavior-in.html) (which _might_ be obsolete by now?) suggests you _do_ need a `HttpHeadOrGet` attribute (ew).

Comment: My comment was sorta accurate. Without [HttpGet], [HttpHead] and only [Route], the client still only sends a HEAD request and succeeds. But Swagger fails. I assumed too much from that failure. The combination allows success from both the client and Swagger.